# getting data from an existing excel file and write into a new excel file filtered by date

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

I'm trying to get from an existing excel file a set of data and trying to write to a new file if only they match the date today. I am trying to do this but I am not sure how to do that.

Existing Excel file contains the following:
[image]

What I would want to do is to get the data which has the employment_date to today and write it in a new excel file. Expected output would be:

[image]

CODE:

```
def recreate_xls_file(src_file_path):
    book_xls = xlrd.open_workbook(src_file_path)
    book_xlsx = Workbook()
    sheet_names = book_xls.sheet_names()
    for sheet_index in range(0,len(sheet_names)):
        sheet_xls = book_xls.sheet_by_name(sheet_names[sheet_index])
        if sheet_index == 0:
            sheet_xlsx = book_xlsx.active
            sheet_xlsx.title = sheet_names[sheet_index]
        else:
            sheet_xlsx = book_xlsx.create_sheet(title=sheet_names[sheet_index])
        headerrow = book_xls.sheet_by_index(0).row_values(0)
        for col in range(0, sheet_xls.ncols):
            sheet_xlsx.cell(row = 1 , column = col+1).value = headerrow[col]

        for row in range(1, sheet_xls.nrows):
            for col in range(1, sheet_xls.ncols):
                if col == 3: #col 16 is the date
                    converted_datetime = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(sheet_xls.cell_value(row, col), book_xls.datemode))
                    converted_datetime2 = converted_datetime.strftime('%#m/%#d/%Y %#I:%M:%S %p')
                    cd_split= converted_datetime2.split()
                    date_str = cd_split[0]
                    date_now = datetime.datetime.now().date().strftime('%#m/%#d/%Y') 
                    if date_str == date_now:
                        sheet_xlsx.cell(row = row+1 , column = 3).value = converted_datetime
                        sheet_xlsx.cell(row = row+1 , column = col+1).value = sheet_xls.cell_value(row, col)
    book_xlsx.save(xlsx_file)
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It would greatly help if you would give us the output you currently have, the one you want to have, and a way to execute your code. All these are part of a [mcve] and help us at providing a good solution -- you can imagine we do not want to lose a hour building the post you should have done. Resulting in you not getting the help we could have provided. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use `pandas`. It allows to solve the problem in couple lines of code (or even one line if you'd like):

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

# read excel table
data = pd.read_excel('1.xlsx', parse_dates=['employment_date'])

# filter data
new_data = data.loc[data['employment_date'] == datetime.date.today(), :]

# save filtered data as excel table
new_data.to_excel('2.xlsx', index=False)
```